# Loading div inside html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, load

I'm using jquery to load my website content once its fully loaded. That works great.

jquery code

```
function check() {
$("#content").load('items.html');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
check(); 
});
```

html

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Is there a way without refreshing the whole page to dynamically load html element (div) when user clicks on one of the items which were already loaded('items.html')?. On one click I want to remove already loaded 'items.html' inside #content div and load new div from any.html file.

So basically, I need to show more info for that particular item by dynamically replacing already loaded items.html and adding new div instead.

I managed to load new html page by adding anchor tags on every item, but it would be much better if I could load only one part(div) of a html file and not a whole page, that way I can write all items informations in only one html file, and then add those div's dynamically when user clicks on any item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check() {
  $("#content").load('items.html #loadable'); // #ID to load
}

$('#loadCont').click(check);
```

[main page example](http://jsbin.com/dogavere/2/edit)
[page 2 example](http://jsbin.com/geqibewo/2/js)

You might also want to put this somewhere

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

As seen from the demo,  `.load()` does already content-replacement, so no need to `.empty()` or `.html('')` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.Try to call the `check()` function on clicking of the element

```
$('element').click(function(){
    check();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I get that, but how can I target specific .html, and then specific div inside that html file with this jquery function? I hope it makes any sense what I'm asking.

Comment: @maddesign this is explain in DOC, read it and be aware, GET requests are cached  https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: That's why I added `also`